# storing selected values of spinner in sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite, spinner

I need to store the value selected from the spinner into my already existing table in sqlite database.I cannot get a clear idea from the internet because it only shows how to enter the spinner values in db and not the selected value.This is the code for implementing spinner(static)

```
 Spinner staticSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.static_spinner);

    // Create an ArrayAdapter using the string array and a default spinner
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> staticAdapter = ArrayAdapter
            .createFromResource(this, R.array.man_array,
                    android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);

    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    staticAdapter
            .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    staticSpinner.setAdapter(staticAdapter);

    Spinner dynamicSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.dynamic_spinner);

    String[] items = new String[] {"rate_of_flow", "30", "40", "50" };

    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, items);
```

My application can use both dynamic and static spinner.I don't have any preference.Can you help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you simply get the selected item and insert the selected value in database like here

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String selected = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();
            //Code to insert selected string in database
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks for your help.I tried implementing it and got this exception --> java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 0, col -1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.What could be the problem?

Comment: It's not the fault of this code, It means `getColumnIndex()` could not find the specified column in the `Cursor`. See where you've used `getColumnIndex()` properly.

Comment: pipe flowrate = c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(FLOW_RATE))     Is this how we retrive value from db?

Comment: Yes it's so. But make sure FLOW_RATE is correct name of your column. If this also didn't work you can pass `0` or `1` directly as index of table like here `c.getString(1)`.

Comment: I'll try that.But I have this doubt.This activity contains a spinner entry as well as text entry.Can I use the same data model object to insert both values into db?

Comment: You can use same model, but in proper way.

Answer (score 1):

Try This:

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            String string = (String) spinner.getItemAtPosition(spinner.getSelectedItemPosition());
            Toast.makeText(YourActivity.this, "Selected Item "+string, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
}
```